# Pull Google Sites data into a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sites

Our team currently uses Google Sites as a platform for our internal WIKI. Our WIKI is quite large and we need a way to better monitor page updates. For example, if a team member creates a new page or modifies an existing page, these changes need to be reviewed and signed off by another team member.

As it stands, we cannot find an app for Google Sites that will help with this process. Our idea is to connect our Google Site with a Google Sheet. The Google Sheet would automatically (1) list every page available on our Google Site, (2) the data the page was last modified, and (3) the person who modified it.

Does anyone know if it's possible to connect a Google Site to Google Sheets in this way?

Comment: [A rebuilt version of Sites was launched on November 22, 2016. Apps Script cannot currently access or modify Sites made with this version, but script can still access classic Sites.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app), which , I think, amounts to a "no" to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, this does not affect us because our WIKI is using Classic SItes.

Comment: Sounds like a catch22; good news for you; but for someone to help you, they need a "classic" site for development.